# find max compared in current year and previous years

Tags: php, sql

Hello i am trying to execute a query wherein i need the max weight of the fish according to the each line weight

i.e if the line weight of a fish is 60 and weight caught is 100 and 200,it should show up only the 200 value and not the 100 value similarly this goes on for all other fishes in the table.

I need to also compare the previous records to the current records(1st JULY to 30 JUNE) and display which record is maximum eg. the record should be overwritten to the new highest record by getting compared to the previous records.

The query till now is as shown in

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f2c76/8

Here i need the table to be as follows:

```
Date            Name  Weight  Line Weight

1970-01-01       abc   200     60 
2014-08-29       abc   100     20 
2000-06-02       abc   100     10 
2008-06-02       pqr   300     60 
2008-06-02       pqr   100     20
```

I am using this into a php webpage,if the sql query is not available please help me with a php view for the same

Please help

Comment: I'm not sure it's what you are looking for, but this snippet gives you the maximum value of weight for each line: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f2c76/28

Comment: @user3114651: If I get it right, the only mismatching field is Date, right? Why are you expecting to get Date="1970-01-01" in first row, if you have this table entry: ('2014-07-05', 'abc', 200,60 ) ?

Comment: Ya i think the sql fiddle i posted earlier works, as i have to compare my previous year records to the current year records i.e 1st july to 30 june,the highest is considered in each line weight